# Insert a <br /> tag after x words using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a `<br />` after 5 words in a title, but the piece of code I'm using doesn't work. Please see below:

```
$("#post-id > h2").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br />" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

This function works well as it is - if you want to add a `<br />` tage after the **first** word. But if I change it to `html.slice(5)` then it doesn't work properly.

How could I fix this so it works fine after 5 words? Or maybe a different approach would be more appropriate? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You try using .text() instead of .html().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#post-id > h2").each(function() {
     var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
     html = html.slice(0,5).join(" ") + "<br />" + html.slice(5).join(" ");
     $(this).html(html);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4chL/

Basic idea is you take the first 5 words via slicing from index zero, and getting 5 elements of the array, join them, add your break tag, then get the remaining elements in the array at index 5 (as its a zero based index) and join them with spaces and dump it on the end

**edit**

for the sake of a full answer and if the OP does want to split after every 5 words, here's another method

```
$("h2").each(function() {
var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
var newhtml = [];

for(var i=0; i< html.length; i++) {

    if(i>0 && (i%5) == 0)
        newhtml.push("<br />");

    newhtml.push(html[i]);
}

$(this).html(newhtml.join(" "));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Z2nM/

Comment: @ClydeLobo Yes it does - check the incorrect html in your fiddle - there's only 1 h2 element.  It does work when there's more.

Comment: You never said after every 5 words, i assumed you meant the first 5 words. Two secs and i'll edit

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for the bit of explanation as well, it definitely makes sense. Thanks - much helpful!

Comment: The problem is that you are splitting only once, not every five words as was requested

Comment: @PabloMescher ?? It does *exactly* what he asked for.

Comment: Oh well, maybe I was thinking on the general case and the op wasn't

Comment: @PabloMescher : I was thinking the same ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could simplify your code to:

```
.replace(/((\w+\W+){5})/, '$1<br/>')
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hPRSK/3). Depending on your definition of word, you can change the `\w+` to whatever suits you.

Answer (score -1):

**Replace your code with:**

```
$(".map .tooltip-inner > h2").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().text();
    var result = html.replace(/\ /g,'<br/>'); 
    $(this).html(result);
});
```

Comment: @Archer The OP does not ask after _every_ 5th word. Only after _the_ 5th word (only once)