# Insert javascript Code with jquery after x words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a javascript code in a html formated text. Therefore I use this jquery code:

```js
function getActualWords(node) {
  return node.textContent.split(/\s+/).filter(function(word) {
    return word.trim().length;
  });
}

function insertElemAfterNthWord(opts) {
  var defaults = {
    'nth': 5,
    'elemText': 'new element',
    'elemTag': 'div'
  };

  for (var prop in opts) {
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      defaults[prop] = opts[prop];
    }
  }

  var d = defaults,
    tag = d.elemTag.replace(/<|>/g, ''),
    elem = document.createElement(tag);

  elem.textContent = d.elemText;

  d.nth = parseInt(d.nth, 10);

  if (d.node) {
    var n = d.node.firstChild,
      words = getActualWords(n),
      wordCount = words.length;

    while ((n.nodeType !== 3 || d.nth > wordCount) && n.nextSibling) {

      n = n.nextSibling;
      words = getActualWords(n);
      wordCount = words.length;
    }
    if (getActualWords(n).length < d.nth) {
      return;
    } else {
      var w = getActualWords(n).slice(0, d.nth).pop(),
        i = n.textContent.indexOf(w);
      n.splitText(i + w.length);
      n.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, n.nextSibling);
      n.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(' '), n.nextSibling);
      n.parentNode.normalize();

      return elem;
    }

  }
}


insertElemAfterNthWord({
  'nth': 10,
  'elemTag': 'span',
  'elemText': 'this is the newly-added text inside the newly-added element!',
  'node': document.querySelector('div > div')
}).classList.add('newlyAdded');
```

```css
span {
  color: #f90;
}
div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.newlyAdded {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsitem_text">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque urna eu pulvinar maximus. Sed elit nunc, vestibulum ut eros vitae, pellentesque rhoncus ipsum. In et metus non diam porttitor maximus iaculis nec lectus. Quisque sodales scelerisque
    auctor. Nam rutrum venenatis eros, eu condimentum erat placerat ut. Pellentesque sed tempus sem, eu viverra ipsum. Vestibulum nec turpis convallis, dapibus massa vitae, posuere mauris. Suspendisse mattis tincidunt lorem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam
    at tincidunt erat, maximus laoreet ipsum.</div>
```

**See jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y9pw7z0p/1/

**found here:**

[Insert a <br /> tag after x words using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030923/insert-a-br-tag-after-x-words-using-jquery)

**Is it possible to replace**

```
'elemText': 'this is the newly-added text inside the newly-added element!'
```

with a javascript code for example adsense?

Comment: You could create a DIV with a special ID or class and populate it via JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `span` balise and replace it easily with jquery like :

```
'elemText':'<span class="adsense">this is the newly-added text inside the newly-added element!</span>'
```

And just replace with Jquery :

```
$('.adsense').html('adsense code');
```